# Variance of a sample median

Tags: statistics, definite-integrals, parameter-estimation, median

Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\text{i.i.d.}\operatorname N(\mu,\sigma^2).$

I think I've only ever seen one way to prove that the sample mean of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ has a smaller variance than does the sample median, and it uses some moderately hefty results and doesn't say what the variance of the sample median is.

Specifically, two theorems are used: The Lehmann–Scheffé theorem from the theory of estimation, and the one-to-one-ness of the two-sided Laplace transform:
$$
\left( \mathcal L g\right)(\theta) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x) e^{\theta x} \, dx. \\[16pt]
\text{If } \mathcal L g = \mathcal L h \text{ then } g=h \text{ a.e.}
$$
Is there an elementary and efficient way to show that the sample median has a larger variance than the sample mean?

And (here's the question on a specific definite integral, justifying one of the tags) is there a closed form for the variance of the sample median?

(Here someone could possibly object that this whole thing is trivially reducible to the case where $\mu=0$ and $\sigma=1.$ The two theorems mentioned above both have hypotheses saying either than something doesn't change as $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ changes or that something is true of all values of $(\mu,\sigma^2).$ So I suppose you could construe this question like this: Supposing the hypothesis $\mu=0,\sigma=1$ is assumed, since there is clearly no loss of generality. How do you prove the result then? Is this a case where it is better to forgo a simplifying assumption that discards no generality?)

Comment: If you are willing to consider, instead of the variance of the median, the _asymptotic_ variance of the median, a simple "delta method" calculation delivers the $s$ so that $\sqrt n(M_n-\mu)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,s^2)$, where $M_n$ is the median of $n$ iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ rvs.  One finds that  $s^2/\sigma^2=\pi/2$  .

Comment: If $Y$ is sample median, then  it can be argued [without Lehmann-Scheffe](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83840/119261) that $E[Y\mid \overline X]=\overline X$. The law of total variance then immediately gives $\operatorname{Var}(Y)\ge \operatorname{Var}[\overline X]$.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& X_1,\ldots,X_n \sim \text{i.i.d.} \operatorname N(0,1) \\
\text{Let } & X_{(1)} < \cdots < X_{(n)} \text{ be the order statistics.}
\end{align}
$$
First suppose $n$ is odd: $n=2k+1$ so that $X_{(k+1)}$ is the median. Then......

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& \Pr(X_{(k+1)}\le x) \\ {} \\
= {} & \Pr(\text{at least $k+1$ of } X_1,\ldots,X_n \text{ are} \le x) \\ {} \\
= {} & \Pr(\text{at least $k+1$ successes in $2n+1$ trials}) \\ {} \\
= {} & \sum_{j\,=\,k\,+\,1}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1} j \Phi(x)^j (1-\Phi(x))^{2n+1-j}. \\ {} \\
\text{Therefore } & \frac d {dx} \Pr(X_{(k+1)} \le x) \\ {} \\
= {} & \sum_{j=k+1}^{2n+1} \binom {2n+1} j \Big( j \Phi(x)^{j-1} (1-\Phi(x))^{2n+1-j} \\
& \qquad \qquad {} - \Phi(x)^j (2n+1-j)(1-\Phi(x))^{2n-j} \Big) \varphi(x)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: So next I would think about whether this sum "telescopes" in a way that we can exploit. Then see what we can do with the resulting density function. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

Some clues: The mean $A_n=\bar X_n$ of a normal sample of size $n$ is unbiased and based on the sufficient statistic for $\mu$ so how could the sample median $H_n$ (also unbiased) but not based on the sufficient statistic have a smaller variance?

Moreover, a basic theorem on asymptotic normality of order statistics (except for max and min), states that: $\frac{H_n - \mu}{c/\sqrt{n}}$ converges to standard normal as $n\rightarrow\infty,$ where $c^2 = 1/4\phi(0) = 2\pi/4=\pi/2,$ so the asymptotic variance is $c^2/n = 1.571/n,$ compared with $1/n$ for $\bar X_n.$

The following simulation based on a million normal samples of size $n=100$ provides an approximation (to about three places).

```
set.seed(2020)
h = replicate(10^6, median(rnorm(100)))
var(h)
[1] 0.01547719  # aprx 1.571/100
```

Also for $n=1000.$

```
set.seed(714)
h = replicate(10^6, median(rnorm(1000)))
var(h)
[1] 0.001568231
```

Comment: Your first paragraph is of course what the posted question already says.